# SGE: view jobs not on hold with qstat

Tags: sungridengine

I'm running some jobs on an SGE cluster.  Is there a way to make qstat show me only jobs that are not on hold?

`qstat -s p` shows pending jobs, which is all those with state "qw" and "hqw".

`qstat -s h` shows hold jobs, which is all those with state "hqw".

I want to be able to see all jobs with state "qw" only and NOT state "hqw".  The man pages seem to suggest it isn't possible, but I want to be sure I didn't miss something.  It would be REALLY useful and it's really frustrating me that I can't make it work.

Other cluster users have a few thousand jobs on hold ("hqw") and only a handful actually in the queue waiting to run ("qw").  I want to see quickly and easily the stuff that is not on hold so I can see where my jobs are in the queue.  It's a pain to have to show everything and then scroll back up to find the relevant part of the output.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out *a* way to show what I want by piping the output of qstat into grep:

```
qstat -u "*" | grep " qw"
```

(Note that I need to search for " qw" not just "qw" or it will return the "hqw" states as well.)

But I'd still love to know if it's possible using qstat options only.

Comment: `qstat -u <user_name> | grep  " qw" ` will list for particular user

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is better and useful, I have defined a `code_script` in my home directory and created an `alias` 
 `alias jobstat 'source <code_script>`

```
echo "user\n------------------------" ;
echo "Running " ` qstat -u user | awk ' { if ($5 == "r") print $0 }' | wc -l` ;
echo "Pending " ` qstat -u user  |  awk ' { if ($5 == "qw" || $5 == "hqw")  print $0 }' | wc -l ` ;
echo "------------------------" ;
echo "Total   " `qstat -u user | awk ' { if ($4 =="user") print $0}' | wc -l `
```

this helps me a lot!